# HTML jekyll index listing links in reverse chronological order

Tags: html, jekyll

I modified some HTML in the Minimal Mistakes jekyll theme to create my own website.  The biggest change being that I added another tab of posts, or a new index of posts.

My problem is that the new tab lists my posts in reverse chronological order, while the original tab still lists the posts correctly (newest first). But when I view the html, the code looks identical.  See the two pages below:

The faulty index:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
{% include _head.html %}
</head>

<body class="post-index">

{% include _browser-upgrade.html %}

{% include _navigation.html %}

{% if page.image.feature %}
  <div class="image-wrap">
  <img src=
    {% if page.image.feature contains 'http' %}
      "{{ page.image.feature }}"
    {% else %}
      "{{ site.url }}/images/{{ page.image.feature }}"
    {% endif %}
  alt="{{ page.title }} feature image">
  {% if page.image.credit %}
    <span class="image-credit">Photo Credit: <a href="{{ page.image.creditlink }}">{{ page.image.credit }}</a></span>
  {% endif %}
  </div><!-- /.image-wrap -->
{% endif %}

<div id="main" role="main">
  <div class="article-author-side">
    {% include _author-bio.html %}
  </div>
  <div id="index">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {% capture written_year %}'None'{% endcapture %}
    {% for post in site.work %}  
      {% capture year %}{{ post.date | date: '%Y' }}{% endcapture %}
      {% if year != written_year %}
        <h3>{{ year }}</h3>
        {% capture written_year %}{{ year }}{% endcapture %}
      {% endif %}
      <article>
        {% if post.link %}
          <h2 class="link-post"><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a> <a href="{{ post.link }}" target="_blank" title="{{ post.title }}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></h2>
        {% else %}
          <h2><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <p>{{ post.excerpt | strip_html | truncate: 160 }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      </article>
    {% endfor %}
  </div><!-- /#index -->
</div><!-- /#main -->

<div class="footer-wrap">
  <footer>
    {% include _footer.html %}
  </footer>
</div><!-- /.footer-wrap -->

{% include _scripts.html %}

</body>
</html>
```

The correct index:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
{% include _head.html %}
</head>

<body class="post-index">

{% include _browser-upgrade.html %}

{% include _navigation.html %}

{% if page.image.feature %}
  <div class="image-wrap">
  <img src=
    {% if page.image.feature contains 'http' %}
      "{{ page.image.feature }}"
    {% else %}
      "{{ site.url }}/images/{{ page.image.feature }}"
    {% endif %}
  alt="{{ page.title }} feature image">
  {% if page.image.credit %}
    <span class="image-credit">Photo Credit: <a href="{{ page.image.creditlink }}">{{ page.image.credit }}</a></span>
  {% endif %}
  </div><!-- /.image-wrap -->
{% endif %}

<div id="main" role="main">
  <div class="article-author-side">
    {% include _author-bio.html %}
  </div>
  <div id="index">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {% capture written_year %}'None'{% endcapture %}
    {% for post in site.posts %}  
      {% capture year %}{{ post.date | date: '%Y' }}{% endcapture %}
      {% if year != written_year %}
        <h3>{{ year }}</h3>
        {% capture written_year %}{{ year }}{% endcapture %}
      {% endif %}
      <article>
        {% if post.link %}
          <h2 class="link-post"><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a> <a href="{{ post.link }}" target="_blank" title="{{ post.title }}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></h2>
        {% else %}
          <h2><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <p>{{ post.excerpt | strip_html | truncate: 160 }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      </article>
    {% endfor %}
  </div><!-- /#index -->
</div><!-- /#main -->

<div class="footer-wrap">
  <footer>
    {% include _footer.html %}
  </footer>
</div><!-- /.footer-wrap -->

{% include _scripts.html %}

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone direct me how to make both pages list the links, recent first.

Also, here is the _config.yml portion related to the posts:

```
collections:
  work:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/

defaults:
  # _work
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: work
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: false
      share: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'faultly' code is dealing with collection. Collection items are sorted in chronological order. The only exception is for `site.posts` that are sorted in reverse chronological order.

To output the `site.work` collection in reverse chronological order, you can do :

```
{% for post in site.work reversed %}
```